# How to solve “build failed with an exception”?

Tags: flutter, gradle, compiler-errors

We already try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

but it does not work for our app, what can i do to solve it?

[Error in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nl4Y.png)

Comment: The command you ran gets more detail about the problem and not supposed to solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter error Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59476081/flutter-error-could-not-determine-the-dependencies-of-task-appcompiledebugjav)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently a [maintenance on Bintray](https://status.bintray.com/incidents/4mzph0y8l6hk?u=s94xyn98c71x) which may explain why you're having this problem all of a sudden.

Note that if you're using a version of Flutter > 1.12, you shouldn't have to configure anything in your `build.gradle` file to setup the location plugin, it could also be the root cause of your issue.