# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies, flutter-debug

I am new to flutter and facing this issue while running my app Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/vitika/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1149

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 48s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
```

when I check flutter.gradle there's not 1149 line.

flutter doctor -v:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.3.0-17.0.pre.120, on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 5.8.0-55-generic, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.3.0-17.0.pre.120 at /home/vitika/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision c42ec8592f (5 weeks ago), 2021-05-28 22:34:02 -0400
    • Engine revision aca8aa2335
    • Dart version 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-165.0.dev)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/vitika/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /home/vitika/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /home/vitika/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.24.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • ASUS X00TD (mobile) • 100.80.74.27:5555 • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
    • Chrome (web)        • chrome            • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.93

• No issues found!
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried running `flutter clean` command?

Comment: Or maybe check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59476081/flutter-error-could-not-determine-the-dependencies-of-task-appcompiledebugjav

Answer (score 0):

add this to build gradle ile in the app  , it worked for me

```
defaultConfig {
        *
        *
        *
        *
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i was getting the same issue:

```
flutter clean .
```

then

```
flutter pub get
```

solved my issue.